# Egg and flour proportion for pasta extruder

Tags: equipment, pasta

Just bought a manual pasta extrusion device from China. It came with no instructions and the box is written in Chinese. By looking at it, it seems that the "1 egg x 100g of flour" dough recipe will not make its way through the tiny holes (or i will have to exercise a lot to make it). Is this the right proportion for the dough for the extrusion tool?

[image]

Comment: 1 egg / 100 grams of flour is somewhat canonical for Italian egg pasta. If you are afraid that the pasta will be too hard to extrude, you can add some olive oil and/or **tiny** amounts of water. The dough does not react linearily to water addition, so you want to add the water teaspoon by teaspoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of flour are you using? If you are using semolina, as expected, you should try to sift it and remove the coarse parts. Also, you can mix 75% semolina and 25% of a softer wheat flour. The egg makes the dough much (much) harder to extrude, you can try substituting water for egg:

- for **453 grams** of semolina, **162 grams** of water

I make my fresh pasta with the wonderful mx700 Simac (which you can find online for about 40/60$) and I can assure you that the pressure applied by the machine is tremendous and when I don't get the mix carefully balanced the motor clearly screams and the machine cracks like it's going to open in half.

[image: My mx700 Simac]

In Venice, Italy we have a traditional manual pasta machine called Bigolaro that resembles a bit the one you posted, but the handle is much larger, hence easier to turn: you should use a metal pipe (on each side) to make your work easier!

[image: bigolaro]

Comment: I have been away for some time, not tested the machine nor the suggestions. I don't want to take the eggs out, so will try using some soft flour. If it is still hard, i will add liquid, as '@Walter A. Aprile' also stated. The answer is complete, and even made me think about building a bench like the Venetian machine you showed. Thanks!